# Start an activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

The error I'm getting: `ERROR here: can't connect to Play.cass`

What am I doing wrong?

```
    public class AppleFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener,
    SensorEventListener {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Log.i("list", "choose:" + musicList.get(arg2) + "this");

     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setClass(getActivity(), Play.class);
   intent.putExtra("song", musicList.get(arg2));
   startActivity(intent);
}
  }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting ?

Comment: post your full logcat

Comment: is `Play` an `Activity`?

Comment: The user: user3410744 is no longer on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Play.class);
 intent.putExtra("song", musicList.get(arg2));
 getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setClass(getActivity(), Play.class); 
 is same Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Play.class);

what the diff in your ans @yashdeep

Comment: The diff is the getActivity before the startActivity

Comment: Difference is that he has pass context of Fragment as a reference to start new Activity.

Comment: Hey, @Bhanu sorry but i can not see your answer in my feed. I don't know why but i cannot see that. Only one answer is there for this question.

Comment: actually i didn't give ans but at my side i use fragment activity i.e start activity directly call i just forgot that  user3410744 only use fragment so +1 for your ans dude and i just compare wd qus